# Keycloak. Put RealmRepresentation using Admin API gives "no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value"

Tags: jackson, keycloak

I want to change settings in my realm using the Admin API. The following GET code works

```
url = keycloak_url + '/admin/realms/master'
headers=...
requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

However, when I try to do a PUT, I get a 500 error.

```
params = dict(registrationAllowed=True, rememberMe=True)
# both below don't work
x = requests.put(url, headers=headers, json=json.dumps(params))
x = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=params)
```

The error in the server logs is:

> Uncaught server error: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   construct instance of
>   org.keycloak.representations.idm.RealmRepresentation (although at
>   least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory
>   method to deserialize from String value ('{"registrationAllowed":
>   true, "rememberMe": true}') at [Source:
>   (io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl); line: 1, column: 1]
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1342)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1031)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:371)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:323)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1366)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:171)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:161)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1574)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:965)
>   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider.readFrom(ResteasyJackson2Provider.java:135)
>   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:66)
>   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(ServerReaderInterceptorContext.java:61)
>   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:56)
>   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalVerificationInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(DigitalVerificationInterceptor.java:36)
>   at
>   ...

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistake on my side, it's

```
x = requests.put(url, headers=headers, json=params)
```